# How to name my own executable in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I created the following Makefile, and it works. It produces an executable named "test_Makefile_my_libs" which happens to be my Fortran code name sans the suffix ".f90".

```
FC = gfortran

FCFLAGS = -g -fbounds-check
FCFLAGS = -O2

FCFLAGS += -I/usr/include

LIBDIR = /homedir/myname/Libraries/
LIBS = $(LIBDIR)/libgfortran_f.a $(LIBDIR)/libmy.a

PROGRAMS = test_Makefile_my_libs

all: $(PROGRAMS)

%: %.o
        $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.f90
        $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean veryclean

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.mod *.MOD

veryclean: clean
        rm -f *~ $(PROGRAMS)
```

But I need an executable name independent of my source code name, say, "myjob.exe". How should I make the appropriate changes in the Makefile without modifying my source code name? (I have tried many different ways, and none worked.)

Comment: I strongly recommend taking a few hours to **read the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)**. This will be useful for you (and not only today). Also, try `make -p` to understand the builtin rules, and take advantage of them.

Comment: just change `PROGRAMS = test_Makefile_my_libs` to `PROGRAMS = myjob.exe` won't help??

Comment: "I strongly recommend taking several hours to RTFM". That defies the purpose of the site for 90% of its content. Also this question is deeper than it seems: with explicit rules, it's straightforward, but what if one wants to do it with implicit rules?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule:

```
myjob.exe: test_Makefile_my_libs.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Also need to add myjob.exe to `PROGRAMS` instead of `test_Makefile_my_libs` so that it becomes the target of `all`

Comment: Many thanks! This works like magic. Although I tried something similar earlier, but apparently failed to get all the details correct.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Could do that, yes, if the OP *wants* it to be the default target.

Comment: I was hoping for an implicit rule method (that does not involve explicit usage of shell renaming). This appears to hardcode explicit rules into the linking.